# Commutative algera reference for algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

I am trying to learn some algebraic geometry (varieties, sheaves, schemes) from a couple of sources (Hartshorne, Harris, Vakil). I find that my commutative algebra background is a bit lacking. I do know the basics of rings, mpodules, chain conditions, localization etc. but there are other things I don't know: dimension theory, valuation rings etc.

Can someone recommend a book that perhaps introduces and/or proves the necessary commutative algebra background while setting up algebraic geometry? I think this will be the best way to approach given my current knowledge, but I haven't been able to find the perfect resource yet.

Comment: Are you asking for a book meant to present algebraic geometry that sets up all the "necessary commutative algebra background" along the way?  Or have you looked at Eisenbud's book on commutative algebra?

Comment: I have looked at Eisenbud's commutative algebra, but I am looking for a reference suggestion for a book that sets up all the "necessary commutative algebra background" along the way.

Comment: How about "Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry" by Kunz?

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that the lack of commutative algebra details in most algebraic geometry textbooks is frustrating. One great source for this is Qing Liu's book 'algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves'. It covers much (but less) of the same material as Hartshorne's chapter II and a bit of chapter III, but actually includes most commutative algebra details.